# How can i chang telephone field input type validation on check out onepage

Tags: checkout, forms, validation

***How can I change  telephone field input type validation on check out onepage ?***

Currently it takes input numeric with no space. I want to change it space with numbers

As an example,

current input format is: 1234567899999

But when i try this input format: 123 45468 99999

it is not working. What should I do to format this number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento uses `Prototype library to manage form validation of  input fields`. This comes in handy, because all you `need to do when writing custom form is to assign a valid class names` to your input fields, and pass the form id to VarienForm object.

you need add  `css class validate-phoneStrict` at field which will do `this type validation. you need to remove validate-number etc validation`

You need see js field validation  at js\prototype\validation.js

```
        <input type="tel" name="billing[telephone]" 
    value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>"
     title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="validate-phoneStrict
     input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>"
 id="billing:telephone" />
```

**and you can also do below format:**

```
(123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890
```

Comment: for reference: the two telephone validation classes and their regEx from validation.js:
`validate-phoneStrict =  /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/`


`validate-phoneLax =  /^((\d[-. ]?)?((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3}))?[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4}$/`